# Add future date-time to pandas df

Tags: python, pandas

This is, I think, a rather simple question which I have not been able to find a proper answer.

I have a pandas dataframe with the following characteristics

```
shape(frame)
Out[117]: (3652, 2)
```

Here 3652 refers to days within a decade (3652 since we have 2 leap years)

I would like to add a third column that shows date range between 2035-01-01 and 2044-12-31

Many thanks

Comment: Have you had a look at [`pd.date_range`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html)

Comment: Yes, but how do I appendix such date range to my frame?

Comment: Something like `df[date] = pd.date_range('2035-01-01','2044-12-31')`? Note that this daterange actually contains 3653 days